# Are the Poulet-numbers of the form $k^2+1$ all squarefree?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, pseudoprimes

A Poulet-number $n$ is a weak Fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ , in other words a composite number $n$ with the property $$2^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$$

The first $34$ poulet-numbers of the form $k^2+1$ (positive integer $k$) are , according to my calculations :

$$[46657, 898705, 2433601, 23736385, 67371265, 96589585, 331240001, 878529601, 1370776577, 4294967297, 8019202501, 80542440001, 287210246401, 351596817937, 422240040001, 682160364901, 1086430982401, 1911029760001, 2359971888401, 13603040532901, 17767236614401, 18677955240001, 26042752304101, 364005569944901, 458631349862401, 598865079758401, 45824890274900101, 189623338816064401, 286245437364810001, 1148717191415062501, 2333246290710627601, 6017402415698251777, 18446744073709551617, 52807456278501210001]$$

They are all squarefree.

Questions :

> - Is my list of the first $34$ poulet-numbers of the form $k^2+1$ correct ?
> - Is every poulet-number of the form $k^2+1$ squarefree ?
> - Are there infinite many Poulet-numbers of the form $k^2+1$ ?

Trial :

Assume $p$ is a prime with $p^2\mid k^2+1$ and $2^{k^2}\equiv 1\mod (k^2+1)$. Then , we have $$2^{k^2}\equiv 1\mod p^2$$ The order $u$ of $2$ modulo $p^2$ is therefore a divisor of $k^2$ , but because of $p\nmid k^2$ we have $p\nmid u$. Therefore we have $u\mid p-1$ , hence $p$ is a Wieferich prime. Can we finish the proof ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Whelp, that sequence isn't in the OEIS. So that's a bummer.

Comment: @Arthur This sequence isn't, but [A135590](https://oeis.org/A135590) is the sequence of values $n$ for which $n^2+1$ are in the OP's list. The lists would seem to match (I checked a few) but OP should give it a thorough check.

Comment: As to your sketch attempt proof: Yes, we have $u \mid k^2$, but we should also have $u \mid p^2 - 1 \implies u \mid p+1 \lor u \mid p-1$. I'm not sure how much that changes your direction. --- One thing to note: via Wikipedia, all the Poulet numbers that are not squarefree in fact have a Wieferich prime as the (only) squared component. The whole Wieferich prime thing to me is crazy--there are almost certainly either $2$ or infinitely many. EDIT: another note from the OEIS sequence: $2^{16}$ and $2^{64}$ appear in it. Other powers of two also might?

Comment: @EricSnyder It is conjectured that there are infinite many Wieferich primes , nothing speaks for exactly two. The third (if it exists) is already very large, according to the mentioned search limit, beyond $10^{17}$.

Comment: @EricSnyder It would be interesting to have a proof that $1093^2$ cannot divide a poulet number of the form $k^2+1$ (the other known Wiefirich prime is not of the form $4k+1$).

Comment: @Peter I read the last result is just two Wieferich primes below 2^64. And heuristically a ten percent chance to find another if the search is extended by a factor 100. And unfortunately no maths improving this search beyond brute force has ever been found. Heuristically there is on average one Wieferich prime between x and x^e or k Wieferich primes between x and x^(exp(k)). Which means it is _slightly_ bad luck not to find the third one.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, the hope that another Wieferich prime will be found is extremely small , so we can concentrate on finishing the proof for the known Wieferich primes.